# Time complexity of dequeue function (queues)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Consider the following operation along with Enqueue and Dequeue operations on queues, where k is a global parameter.

```
MultiDequeue(Q){
     m = k 
     while ((Q is not empty) and (m > 0))  
     { Dequeue(Q) 
       m = m – 1 
      }
}
```

What is the worst case time complexity of a sequence of **n queue** operations on an initially **full** 
queue having n elements.?

(A) $\Theta(n) $

(B) $\Theta(n+k)$

(C) $\Theta(nk)$

(D) $\Theta(n^2)$

---

Here suppose we do one dequeue operation, then the loop will run for min(n,k) times. Now remaining 1 operation can be 1 enqueue operation which will take O(1) time so total complexity in this case will be O(min(n,k)).

Suppose we have k=1 and do (n-1) dequeue operations then it will take k*(n-1) time for multideqeue function and remaining one enqueue operation will take O(1) time . So in total we are getting O(kn) time in this case.

I am confused on how to handle 'k' parameter when we are calculating complexity.

**NOTE :- n queue operations can be any combination of enqueue/dequeue/multi-dequeue(as defined) operation.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dukeling You can assume it n. I will include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $\Theta(n)$. Observe that if you are limited by $n$ operations, the total number of elements that ever enter the queue is less than or equal to $n$. Furthermore, every element is processed at most twice: once when it enters the queue, and once when it leaves the queue, therefore the total time is at most a constant times $n$.

Comment: Also why is $\Theta(n+k)$ not the correct answer?

Comment: If at the beginning I perform 1 multi-D operation with k=n then it will take O(n) time. Now 'n-2' enqueue operations will take O(n-2) time. Now again 1 multideqeue operation will take O(n-2) time. So total O(3n-4).

Comment: The $k$ parameter is irrelevant to the complexity. Also, $\Theta(3n-4) = \Theta(n)$, I suggest you review the Landau notation.

Comment: I know that constants are irrelevant in landau notation. Wouldn't $\Theta(n+k)$ be more precise ?

Comment: No. $k$ is irrelevant.

Comment: So do we **never** include constants in landau notation as growth rate only depends on input size ?

Comment: FYI, there is no consensus on what $\Theta(n+k)$ actually means, in that Bachmann-Laundau notation in the case of multiple parameters is not formally defined in a consistent way that everyone agrees on. This is the key paper that explores the topic: http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf